# How to use sed between single quotes?

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have some short script which looks like this:
It's a way to execute bash inside a groovy command.

```
sh (script: 'printf "${INFO} | sed 's/^[^\/]*://g'"',returnStdout: true).trim()
```

The value of `INFO` is `test/word/fine`.

With the script above I want to 'delete' everything till (and including) the first `/`. I can not make it work with the single quotes between single quotes. If that works I can check if my `\/` will work.

Comment: `sh (script:` is not valid `sh` (or Bash) syntax. In what context are you trying to use this?

Comment: What shall the colon do in `sed 's/^[^\/]*://g`?

Comment: This is just an example, right?  Regexp replacing in a string can be done way more efficient in groovy than firing up a shell and some more processes.  It would also help, if you would tag that question with the "source of `sh`".  E.g. `jenkins` maybe?

Comment: @cfrick It's indeed inside a jenkinsfile. Where I need to parse an env var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently Groovy allows you to use triple quotes so you *don't* have to force the command to be in single single quotes (sic).

```
sh """printf "${INFO}" | sed 's/^[^\/]*//'"""
```

Notice also the placement of the double quotes in the `printf` command.  A better still solution would be to say `printf '%s' "${INFO}"` but ... do you really need the shell to interpolate the value of the variable `INFO`, and if so, why are you not simply doing `sh 'echo "${INFO#*/}"'`?

If indeed you only want the first occurrence to be replaced, the `/g` flag is superfluous, so I took it out.  Your regex is anchored to the beginning of the string so it will only ever find a single match to replace, but saying "replace all occurrences on a line" when apparently that's precisely not what you want is misleading and confusing at best.

If indeed your test data doesn't contain a colon, the colon in your regex was wrong, so I took that out, too.

Commonly, we use a different separator like `s%^[^/]*/%%` so we don't have to backslash-escape slashes in our `sed` substitutions.

Answer (score 1):

***Solution 1st:*** Following simple `sed` may help you on same.

```
echo "test/word/fine" | sed 's/\([^/]*\)\/\(.*\)/\2/'
```

***Solution 2nd:*** No need to use `sed` use bash parameter expansion:

```
var="test/word/fine"
echo "${var#*/}"
word/fine
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll upvote it, but I still need to use this between the single quotes of printf in the beginning.

Comment: @DenCowboy, could you please elaborate what you are trying to achieve? As it is not clear, you had asked about the `INFO`'s output which I provided. Please be clear in your question and update you post with more proper details.

Comment: @DenCowboy, also `.trim()` doesn't look like bash, looks like some language if I am not wrong, please mention more details on same, could try to help on same then.

Comment: It's using a bash script inside groovy

Comment: @DenCowboy, not sure about groovy, please do mention expected output clearly with respect to bash since bash and sed tags are added.

Comment: The `sed` command is needlessly complicated. Just `sed 's%^[^/]*/%%'` would do.